# Eclipse source code download

Tags: eclipse

In new Eclipse we have feature to right click XSD and generate an XML from it.Can someone please guide me where will I get the source code for this feature of Eclipse.I guess Eclipse is open source so even its source code should be available.

Any sort of help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Wow. I had to come to SO to get the source for eclipse because eclipse.org (their own website) uses a fork with a cork.