# Downloading Eclipse Platform Source Code

Tags: java, eclipse

Before this question is blocked for duplication, I would like to say that it is more specific than [Downloading Eclipse's Source Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890757/downloading-eclipses-source-code) and [Downloading Eclipse Source Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12646058/downloading-eclipse-source-code) and [Eclipse source code download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8892018/eclipse-source-code-download) , as well as they do not provide I clear way to download the code.

I need to analyse the eclipse source code through metrics more specifically the platform source code. First of all, I would like to know which are the packages that composes the Eclipse platform. Next, I need to download the platform source code, however I already tried different approach with no success. The ways that I already tried:

1) First, I tried to download the RCP SDK from (archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/), however, there is only a set of .jar files inside.

2) When I select the package related to platform (git.eclipse.org/c/?ofs=350), and next select the branch (for example, R2_0_1 ), the tree tab shows that it has only one .java file in the src folder (for example: http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.git/tree/platform/org.eclipse.platform/src/org/eclipse/core/launcher?h=R2_0_1).

3) I also tried to get it by cloning the git repository as suggested by eclipse website (http://projects.eclipse.org/projects/eclipse.platform/developer), the same problems happens, there is only one .java file when you select src folder.

4) I tried to identify the packages which compose the eclipse platform by analyzing the Bug repository ([http://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/buglist.cgi?bug_status=**all**&content=platform&limit=0&list_id=10384608&product=Platform&query_format=specific](http://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/buglist.cgi?bug_status=__all__&content=platform&limit=0&list_id=10384608&product=Platform&query_format=specific)). However, there are some components listed in the bug repository(such as, 
eclipse.platform.common.git, eclipse.platform.git and eclipse.platform.news.git) that are not listed here (git.eclipse.org/c/?ofs=350). This way, I`m not able to identify which components compose the platform.

This way, I would like to know if is there any way to download the Eclipse Platform source code and identify its packages.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://git.eclipse.org/c/ is the home of all the source of all of eclipse.

Comment: I agree, however if you clone any platform package in https://git.eclipse.org/c/?ofs=350, it has few or none .java files. It is very strange. For example, try to look at https://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.common.git/tree/

Comment: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/454650/

Comment: Do you know which set of packages composes the Eclipse PLatform? I need to know in order to perform my study.